# App level or Global steam listening in Flutter

Tags: flutter, stream, agora.io

Dear Flutter Stream Experts,

I am still learning Flutter.

I have a Stream in one **View1** where I **user1** makes video calls (add/delete data) in steam.
I have **view2**, where **user2** listens to the above stream (pick up the call).

The above setup works as long as the other **user2** is in **view2**. My goal is that **user2** should able to get pick-up call notifications **anywhere in the app** not just in **view2**. How to accomplish the global or app-level listening to Stream?

Really appreciate any tips, pointers or guidance.

Answer (score 0):

To implement something like a push notification you need to send a signal to the other screen. One easy way to do this in your application would be by using Agora RTM SDK. So once the user joins registers on your application they can join a common channel or "lobby". Now whenever a user tries to call the other user they can send a message to the other user and once that message is received you can trigger the notification locally. You can refer this guide: https://docs.agora.io/en/All/faq/call_invite_notification